# onSharedPreferencesChangeListener with value of the key?

Tags: java, android

Is there a way where I can find value of the changed key in the `onSharedPreferencesChangeListener` which passes only the *key*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can,

```
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged (SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key){
String changedValue = sharedPreferences.getString(key,"");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look into the documentation

```
public abstract void onSharedPreferenceChanged (SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key)
```

> Called when a shared preference is changed, added, or removed. This may be called even if a preference is set to its existing value.

---

> sharedPreference: The SharedPreferences that received the change.
>
> key: The key of the preference that was changed, added, or removed.

**Here key corresponds to the value that's changed.**

Comment: I need the value of that **key**